# How do i add a click event to the names in the dropdown list to display the grade of the student clicked on in an alert. It has been a pain , pls thax

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, display

This is the Main HTML page and the task was to create a dropdown list with student names and on click it should display their grade in an alert box. This is a project I'm giving a second look to improvr my grade and even after learning more, I'm still struggeling to get the final code.
//HTML





Task2

JavaScript

This is the creation of the map

```
    let avrGrades = new Map()
    
    avrGrades.set("Jade", 90)
    avrGrades.set("Vel", 88)
    avrGrades.set("Sky", 60)
    avrGrades.set("Rian", 70)
    avrGrades.set("Lizz", 90)
```

I ran a test loop here to see if the key vale pairs are being read.

```
    for(let [key, value] of avrGrades){
        console.log(key + " " + value)
    }
```

Creating the Drop-down list with was quite simple to be honest.

```
    for(let key of avrGrades.keys()){
        let classList = document.getElementById("classList")
        //Creating an id attribute
        let att =document.createAttribute("id")
        att.value = "option"
        //Creating the option Element
        let listItem = document.createElement("option")
        //Adding the attribute to the option element
        listItem.setAttributeNode(att)
        listItem.innerHTML = key
        classList.appendChild(listItem)
       
    }
```

This sows the grade on click and here is were I am struggeling, i tried a few things but nothing works.

```
    let show = document.getElementById("option")
    show.addEventListener("click", function(){
        for(let value of avrGrades.values()){
            alert(value)
        }
    
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I adjust your code like that:

```js
const avrGrades = new Map();
const classList = document.getElementById("classList");

avrGrades.set("Jade", 90)
avrGrades.set("Vel", 88)
avrGrades.set("Sky", 60)
avrGrades.set("Rian", 70)
avrGrades.set("Lizz", 90)


for (const key of avrGrades.keys()) {
  const listItem = document.createElement("option")
  listItem.innerHTML = key
  classList.appendChild(listItem)
}

classList.addEventListener("change", function() {
  alert(avrGrades.get(classList.options[classList.selectedIndex].text))
})
```

```html
<select id='classList'></select>
```

You try to use multiple same `id`, but the ids **must be unique**, i simple use text of selected option for use [.get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get) and alert the value of grade

Reference:

- [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)
- [HTMLSelectElement.selectedIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex)

Comment: Have you test my code?

Answer (score -1):

Your initial code should work if you specify a unique ID for each one of the option. At the moment you have

```
let att =document.createAttribute("id")
att.value = "option"
```

so each option has the same ID `option`. Try using something unique like `option-{key}` for each one, and set the click for each ID.

You can also remove this ID issue by targeting the elements using a class name instead of an ID

```
let shows = document.getElementsByClassName("option")
for (var i = 0; i < shows.length; i++) {
    shows[i].addEventListener('click', [your function]);
}
```

assuming you give these elements a class with name `option`